# New version react router doesn't work with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

maybe this issue is because the new version of the react router have few days, but I have been reading about this issue and I want to clarify what is going on. I am using the last version of the react router and I want to do the routing through redux. I follow the steps that are listed in the documentation of the redux router module: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux, but I receive this error when I make the implementation: (I know that the issue is in the server render)

```
Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM
```

Here is my code (the important parts):

**server.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

lisaApp.get('*', function (req, res) {
  const context = {};

  const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
          <Routes />
        </StaticRouter>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>,
  );

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  if (context.url) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: context.url,
    });
    res.end();
  }

  res.write(
    renderToStaticMarkup(<Layout title={req.title} content={html} />),
  );

  res.end();
}
```

**client.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from './store';

render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
      <BrowserRouter history={createHistory()}>
        <Routes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>),
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './reducer';

const history = createHistory()
const middlewareHistory = routerMiddleware(history)

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    reducer,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(
    middlewareHistory,   
    thunk
  )
);

export default store;
```

**component.js (dispatch)**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onNavigateTo(dest) {
      dispatch(push(dest));
    }
  };
};
```

Obviously the dispatch, from my component never is called. Anyone can me clarify me where I am wrong? or maybe this feature is not implemented yet in the react router redux module? In advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *BrowserRouter*, use *ConnectedRouter* from the react-router-redux library:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import store from './store';

render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={createHistory()}>
                <Routes />
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>),
    document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, first I want to thank you for your answer, I tried your suggestion but it does not work, I think is because the issue is about the server render, since the client side is fine. The issue is because the 'store' is the same between client and server.

Comment: Ah, OK, I missed the part of your question where you state the problem is related to rendering on the server. When rendering on the server, you should use StaticRouter. I have a similar setup and use different scripts for intializing on the server- and on the client-side. Server-side uses StaticRouter, client-side uses ConnectedRouter.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my code, I am using StaticRouter in my server side, But the 'store' in the Provider is shared by the server side and the client side, so, because of that when I compile the app shows me the error. Do you have an implementation with the new version of the react-router.dom?

Comment: I fixed the issue in order to avoid the error. I use createBrowserHistory module from history library, and createMemoryHistory module from the same one. But now, the dispatch doesn't make the 'push' action, but I know it is called, because the logger shows me the data of the call

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue few days ago. In your BrowserRouter you manually create and pass a browserHistory object. Then, whenever you need access to the history object you import it, like it happens in your store.js, which is shared between the server and the client. However, on the server there is no DOM, hence the error.

I fixed the issue by NOT creating the history object manually, this is not needed since you use the BrowserRouter. As stated in the documentation, the BrowserRouter is:

> A <Router> that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

Instead of importing the history manually whenever you need it, just use the handy **withRouter** higher order component. This way, in your props you will get access not only to the history, but also to the closest <Routes>'s match. Read more about it [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

Regarding your last point about the dispatch, you are right that it's not called. Whenever you create a component via the connect of react-redux, remember to wrap it with the **withRouter** higher order component. Read more about it [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration).

I believe the above will fix your issue. I can share a working example if you want me to, but my solution is very similar to what you have, with the exception of my above comments.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me.

I used *ConnectRouter* from the "react-router-dom" library. Along with it i used *BrowserRouter* from the "react-router-dom" library. **Now i am able to use React+Redux+Routing happily.

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { createStore } from "redux";
    import rootReducer from "./reducers";
    import App from "./App";
    import { connectRouter } from "connected-react-router";
    import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
    export const history = createHistory();
    const store = createStore(connectRouter(history)(rootReducer));
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

I hope this will work for you as well.

Happy coding!!!